# Automatic "Submit" after onload

Tags: jquery

So, here is the `form` that I have:

```
<form class="cart" method="post" >
    <button type="submit" id="add_to_cart_auto_button" class="add_my_post"><?php echo $item->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?></button>
</form>
```

Here is jQuery to trigger automatic `click` once the page is loaded:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
    jQuery(window).load(function() {   
        jQuery("#add_to_cart_auto_button").trigger('submit');    
        return false;
    });   
// ]]></script>
```

But the code itself is not doing anything (no error, no action).
So, once the page is loaded, I want this button to be automatically clicked to trigger next steps.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `.submit()` method instead. https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: @IvanSivak so you suggest `.submit()` which without arguments is shortcut for `.trigger('submit')`? What is the point for this?

Comment: If you want to trigger `click` - why do you trigger `submit`? It doesn't sound logical. Have you tried `.trigger('click')`? And I still don't understand whether it makes any sense to submit form on page loading done at all or not.

Comment: Yeah, I tried pretty much all those suggested, but not getting it working. I got `alert('loaded');`. However, the button inside of the form is not working. I tried @samir approach which was `$( "form.cart" ).trigger( "submit" );` and it pretty much bypassed the `button` function and got to the end result which is not what I wanted to work. Anyway, thanks for the help, and I might know what's happening. I will keep you guys updated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

submit event is applicable for `form` NOT for the `input`. You are trying to trigger `submit` event for the `input`. Please use following instead:

```
$( "form.cart" ).trigger( "submit" );
```